# How to plan the composition of astrophotography?

Tags: astrophotography, composition

I want to shoot the Milky Way, some constellations, and planets.  I want to include some natural landscapes in these photos, similar to these:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/35492781@N08/4665431960/in/faves-blakeperdue/
http://www.flickr.com/photos/digitallion/3824172978/in/faves-blakeperdue/

I want to plan the composition of some shots in advance given my limited time on location. Given a specific date/time and your GPS coordinates or city location, what tools are available to tell you where the Milky Way, planets and constellations will be in the sky?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Stellarium](http://www.stellarium.org/) is great tool for showing astronomical bodies.  And its free!  Set your location, change your light pollution parameters and go!

Check on the light pollution for potential sites with this Google Earth [overlay](http://bbs.keyhole.com/ubb/ubbthreads.php?ubb=download&Number=130109&filename=269838-ArtificialNightSkyBrightnessforNorthAmerica.kmz) - just have Google Earth installed first and double clicking the downloaded file should work.

Comment: Stellarium is awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know of the data source for the artificial light overlay? I ask because I'm interested in getting data for Australia rather than the USA.

Comment: @fmark - sorry I don't.  I thought I remembered seeing a worldwide one, but I can't find it now.

Comment: No worries.  I'll report back here if I track one down.